# Keras Model with 2 inputs during training, but only 1 during inferencing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

A similar question has been asked earlier by someone but the answer was not satisfactory.

Given a model made using Functional API in keras.

During training the model we have two inputs and one output. One input is image. Another input is an array of costs that is needed for custom loss function.

During inferencing however we will get only image as input and no costs are there. Hence only one input and one output.

How to adapt the same model which has been trained on two inputs for inferencing ?

The model during training is somewhat like this :

```
input1 = Input(shape=(64,64,3)) #RGB Image
input2 = Input(shape=(4,))#Costs associated with the image, input to the custom loss function
conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3 , padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(input1)
#Other layers
output = Dense(6)(x) # last layer gives classification output

model = Model(inputs = [input1, input2] , outputs = output)
model.compile(loss = custom_loss_function(input2) , optimizer = 'adam')
```

This is the model during training.

What to do during inferencing when only one input for the image is needed and no cost inputs are present ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a "dummy" input if it doesn't affect the forward pass

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your inference model in a training model.

In pseudo-code:

```
def make_model():
  input1 = Input(...)
  conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3 , padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(input1)
#Other layers
  output = Dense(6)(x) # last layer gives classification output
  return keras.Model(input1, output)

def make_train_model():
  input1 = Input(...)
  input2 = Input(...)
  m_inner = make_model()
  output = m_inner(input1)
  model = keras.Model([input1, input2], output)
  model.compile(...)
  return model, m_inner
```

You can train using model and save the inner model for inference.

Comment: Can we directly pass the m_inner to the output or we have to do get the output layer like this:    model =keras.Model([input1,input2],  m_inner.outputs)

Comment: @ArkaMaji edited answer. The cleanest solution is to use the inner model as a layer. You could have also used m_inner.outputs but using the fact that a model is a layer is more elegant and composable.